# What are a group of people who live in the same place like city, state or nation, called?

Tags: terminology

1)What are a group of people who live in the same place like city, state or nation, called? 
2)What are the group of people who are part of the same institution or organization called?

Comment: city - citizens, state - people or Alaskan, Hawaiian, etc, nation - nation/people, members for institution or organization

Comment: a **community**

Comment: @Tower of Tesla community can be used for both the cases, right?

Comment: a community surely can mean a nation in a country, but it is rarely used for it. Rather, it is more often used to describe people in small towns or counties. You don't want to use a community for people in the same institution or organization.

Comment: That's true. A **community** is *a group of people living in the same place or having a particular characteristic in common*. - http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/community ... typically small areas

Comment: This shows no research and is not specific enough.

Comment: nation: compatriots

Answer (score 4):

I think this very much depends on context as to which would be the best word

1) Group of people who live in the same place like city, state or nation

**Citizen** would seem to be pretty good. But it does imply a political region, which may not be contiguous. So you might not say they are living in the same place. For a country, though, I think it would generally work well.

However, citizens sounds a bit pompous for a small region like a town. I’d suggest **locals**. As a collective, **community** would work well also.

And as has been pointed out, if it’s a particular region, you could use the **demonym**: e.g. New Yorker or Texan.

2) Group of people who are part of the same institution or organization

As Rathony said, **member** would work well.

But there may be a more specific word depending on the type of institution or organisation. For example 'soldiers' for people who are part of the army.

Comment: I think this explains well. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

[**Denizen**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/denizen):

> A person, animal, or plant that lives or is found in a particular place: denizens of field and forest  (-- Oxford Dictionaries Online)

The distinction with *citizen* is that the latter's presence in a place is based on a legal or other recognised standing.  A *denizen* may or may not have that justification.